# Determining destination repository in outgoing hook

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I'm attempting to write a Mercurial hook that blocks pushes under certain conditions, but to determine whether to block the push it needs to know the repository the push would be going out to. I know that ideally, this would be done in a `prechangegroup` hook on the remote repository side, but that's not possible in my case - see my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925099/reading-command-line-arguments-from-mercurial-prechangegroup-hook) for why. (I liked Ry4an's suggestion, but I have to do this for a whole bunch of repositories, so creating a duplicate for each one doesn't seem like the way to go.)

Anyway, I was initially doing this in a `pre-push` hook, but that's only called under very specific circumstances; in particular, if the user has an alias defined for `push`, then my hook won't get called, which means it could be inadvertently bypassed. My next thought was the `preoutgoing` hook, which is definitely more foolproof - it could get called in situations other than a push, but those are easy enough to filter out using the passed `source` parameter.

However, the `preoutgoing` hook doesn't have the destination repository available to it; there's even [a bug filed](http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2859) for that, but it doesn't do me much good right now. Presently, I'm working around this by having two hooks; a `pre-push` one that determines the destination, and then the `preoutgoing` one which actually acts on it. Of course, it's possible the `pre-push` hook doesn't run, but in that circumstance I just warn the user their push is potentially unsafe and give them the option to abandon it.

I have two questions. Firstly, is there a better way to accomplish this? Secondly, if there isn't, is it safe to assume that the `repo` object passed to both my hooks (they're both in-process) will be the same? In other words, if I do something like

```
repo.some_custom_property = outgoing_url
```

in my `pre-push` hook, is it guaranteed that the `preoutgoing` hook that's called subsequently will receive the same `repo` object and therefore have access to my custom property through that? I know I can do this through environment variables or temp files, but this seemed nicer and I don't have to worry about cleaning up after it. I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611045/mercurial-hooks-pass-information-between-hooks), but it didn't really help much.